# Why is my Hem server not watching my spine project

Tags: node.js, npm, spine.js

I have a spine project that was running fine on my previous laptop, but now I have a new machine and I can't get it to build or watch my project with spine. When I do `hem watch -d` it says `Watching application` but then immediately quits that proces again.

There are no errors thrown or anything, I'v tried deleting the old `node_modules` and npm install again, that didn't work, and I don't get any additional info when running the command with the verbose option.

I would love to be able to provide more info but I don't know how to debug this problem. How would I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue with a lot of version reverting. This is definitely not the way to do it, but if you run into the same problem, try this:

node version 0.10.18

npm version 1.3.8

hem version 0.2.7